# Python serialization in queue from hazelcast

Tags: python, queue, hazelcast

I have a very important  problem for me. I have a task to get an object out of the queue in hazelcast, and then convert it to an object in the python. I'm using a python client. I looked through the entire repository(https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-python-client), but I did not find how to get custom objects out of the queue and convert them to objects.And when I use  method take(), some Future objects  come to me, but through the terminal on the machine I see that the number of objects does not change.

(Objects are written on another machine via java-client )

With this code i've got this result:

`my_q = client.get_queue('qmQueue')
new_el = my_q.take()
print(new_el)`

```
<hazelcast.future.Future object at 0x7fd0c4ca1410>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast Python Client is fully asynchronous. By  default it returns a `future` object where you can retrieve the result using `future.result()`.

```
my_q = client.get_queue('qmQueue')
new_el = my_q.take().result()
print(new_el)
```

If you want to use blocking API instead of async then you should use the convenience method to get the queue

```
my_q = client.get_queue('qmQueue').blocking()
new_el = my_q.take()
print(new_el)
```

Comment: asimarslan, thank you very much, but I had a slightly different question. I have custom classes that have been put into the database through the java client. How do I configure the queue configuration so that I can serialize my object into a class on the python?